# Can't create a new Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new rails project (just like `rails new bloccit`). But I get a strange error and can't continue.

This is the error I get:

```
 /Users/marcvanderpeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rails:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/marcvanderpeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rails-4.2.0/bin/rails (LoadError)
from /Users/marcvanderpeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
from /Users/marcvanderpeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /Users/marcvanderpeet/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Any clues on what is causing this problem?

Comment: Can you run ruby -v and rails -v?

Comment: No @facundofarias i cant run rails -v. It gives me the same error. Any thoughts on where to go from here?

Comment: I guess it's something with the rails installation. Which OS are u using?

Comment: Try installing it again with: $ brew install ruby

Comment: But the problem has to do with rails right? (cause I cant run rails -v) what the the use of installing ruby again then?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! You are right, then $ gem install rails
$ rails -v